# Can I charge my PA with a Makita 18v battery and an adapter?

Tags: charger

[image][image][image]

I have an 18v 3A power brick that is used to charge a portable PA system with an internal battery (internal battery is 14.8v 2600mA - ie 4x18650  Li batteries). The PA system probably has the circuitry to charge Li batteries inside it.

When not at home, I wondered if it would be possible to charge the system with an 18v makita battery with a simple battery adapter that would have the correct plug to plug in to the back of the PA charge port.

Can I simply put a plug connector on to the makita battery adapter and plug it in to the PA system?

I've attached some pictures for explanation.

Comment: Assuming the device have enough margins on voltage since a fully charged battery will be 21 V and likewise accept lower than 18 V as the battery is discharged, it should work. The manufacturer will never allow it but it's up to you to risk it. If it was mine, I would crack it open and check the charging circuitry on the inside. If you are lucky, there is some easily identifiable DC/DC converter which you can look up the datasheet for.

Comment: Amazing, thanks, I need to open it up to replace the battery anyway as it's a dud, so will take some photos of the converter to check it's stats. Thank you for the quick reply :-)

Comment: Had a quick look, and there's lots of components which say "25V" which I'm hoping means it's protected up to 25v? I'll post a photo

Comment: No, it only means some components (capacitors) have have 25 V limit. You need to focus and probably draw up a schematic on the 18 V input part, MOSFETs and ICs.

Comment: Uploaded a clearer pic. Jk1 is the power input... I have no idea what I'm looking at lol

Comment: Then it will be a great learning experience to reverse engineer it. Looks multi-layered so it won't be easy. If you can't work it out, you have already found a solid 25 V limit but some IC's could very well come with even lower limit if it's a poor design. I would never design for less than 30 V with 18 V nominal input unless it was a toy. Consider your time spent versus product cost and just YOLO it.

Comment: Thanks again for your message. On the circuit, the first thing the circuit interacts with is an SS34 diode, which looking at the data sheet limits  voltage to 30. I'm sure it will be fine..... Well gonna give it a go. Wish me luck :-)

Comment: @ShahzadAhmed - Also don’t forget that fully depleted, your Makita battery will be nearing only 15volts, and your PA systems fully charged is 16.8 volts, so that will be a problem!  You could get a cheap dc-dc boost/buck module on AliExpress that you Makita battery connects to first, then the boost/buck module would output a constant voltage that you could assign to 18v and problem solved!